# JQuery function does not work anymore after pagination

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, pagination

I am using CodeIgniter for my website. On one page I show different vehicles. The user can browse through all results with pagination.

I also have a few dropdown boxes which the user can use to further filter the results. One dropdown box contains the main category with brands (Mercedes, DAF, ...)

The second dropdown box contains vehicle types. For this box I created a JQuery function which updates the contents of the box based on the brand selected in the first box. This does not work anymore when I click on a pagination link to go to the next page. I guess it has something to do with the fact that the function is created in the ready part. Can someone help, please?

**JQuery code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateTypes(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "merk_id=" + $('#selection').val()  + "&voertuig=" + $('#voertuig').val(),
        url: "dropdown",
        success: function(msg){
            if (msg != ''){
                $("#selectionresult").html(msg).show();

            }
        }
    });
}


    $("#selection").change(updateTypes);


    // Update types when entering the second box with the mouse
    $("#selectionresult").mouseenter(updateTypes);
```

The first box has an id=selection and the second box has an id=selectionresult

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I still can't get it solved. Perhaps if someone would like to take a look at http://www.smz.be/argodots/trekkers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the  `.html()` call wipes out the previously-bound `click` event handler. Use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) instead of [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click). Change

```
$("#selection").change(updateTypes);
```

to

```
$("#selection").live('change', updateTypes);
// or
$('some ancestor of #selection').delegate('#selection', 'change', updateTypes);
```

Doing this binds the event listener higher up the DOM tree, so the listener won't get obliterated by the `$("#selection").html()` call.

Comment: I tried 'code' $("#selection").live('change', updateTypes);
but this does not work. And I think I cannot use delegate because there is no ancestor of #selection. Do you perhaps have another idea what this could be? Thanks!

Comment: body will always be an ancestor of #selection

Answer (score 0):

Are the selects being re-rendered when you paginate? If so, you need a way to bind the `.change()` and `.mouseenter()` events again, since the original objects are no longer present.

Take a look at [jquery.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: No, I think the selects are not re-rendered when paginating. I even have the impression that the whole page is not re-rendered, but I am not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$('body').delegate('#selection', 'propertychange change', function(){ 
  updateTypes();
});
```